# Is it a bad practice to use UpdatePanel for Ajaxing in MVC views?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In a MVC app, I'm trying to refresh a content of a view every few seconds. Normally in MVC you call controller method that returns a partial views (jQuery is an option to call the controller). What I'd like to know is whether it is a bad practice to use UpdatePanel for Ajaxing in MVC views?

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to use Ajax in ASP.NET MVC is to use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Why would you want to use an UpdatePanel? Maybe you should reconsider your choice of using MVC over WebForms?

Comment: +1 for The preferred way to use Ajax in ASP.NET MVC is to use jQuery Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You could preload the content and make it change every few seconds.